# Sportsmanship badge should also consider accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, badges, voting, sportsmanship-badge, competing-answers

The Sportsmanship badge is awarded for voting on 100 answers competing with one's own. The rules are currently that votes count only for questions on which the user has posted a positive-voted answer.

I propose that criteria for the Sportsmanship badge counts votes made for a user who posted the accepted answer. The difference between this and the current rules is that currently the accepted answer is not considered if it does not have a positive score (i.e., has a zero score).

Obviously, the answer that the requestor accepts is not simply an answer posted just for the purpose of cheating the system and earning the badge underhandedly. Accepting an answer is a kind of implicit "vote" (conceptually) that should be considered in the criteria of the aforementioned badge.

**EDIT:** If you are downvoting this, please comment on *why* you think this is a bad idea. I think most people glanced over the message and assume I am saying all zero-vote answers should be considered, which is clearly not the case.

**EDIT:** As with essentially all other badges, users should not be able to cheat by answering their own questions.

Comment: y'know, maybe if you'dve expanded that answer a bit after seeing the competition it would've gotten an up-vote...

Comment: @Shog9, yes, clearly in my example and clearly sometimes that occurs, but there are frequently answers that do not get votes because they are more precise than earlier answers but are not posted until the popularity of the question dies (i.e., when it is no longer on the front page or two).

Comment: So, is your proposal that the votes for competing answers should count when you gave **an accepted answer OR a positive-voted answer**?

Comment: @trutheality, I modified the request's body to make it more clear, though I am sure it is too late to salvage this post because enough people have downvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

**The following loophole was closed in a question edit:**

This introduces the following method for getting the badge:

- Ask a question
- Upvote answers
- Answer your question
- Mark your own answer as correct
- Repeat

Comment: we already have accepted-but-not-by-you as a category when calculating, say, Unsung Hero.

Comment: I edited my post for this, but essentially all badges that could be unfairly won using one's own answer have special exceptions. This is more of a detail than an objection.

Comment: @Justin Satyr, I did upvote, I just thought this is important to point out.